# How to add Silverlight to Chrome in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, plugins, moonlight

How to add Silverlight to Chrome in 12.04? I found a couple of guides to add Moonlight plugin to Chrome browser, but nothing that works as of yet.

Comment: Here's your problem. Silverlight is Microsoft software, and Moonlight support was dropped AFIK. So, to add Silverlight into Chrome would be difficult while running Ubuntu.

Comment: So, I can't add Moonlight plugin to Chrome? I have read tons of people out there having added it successfully, but as I said, I can't follow theirs steps :(

Comment: Wait, what do you need silverlight for? There may be a workaround for a specific item.

Comment: And, again, after looking, it would appear the after Natty, moonlight kind of died. http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/ - Seems to have something that may work.

Comment: [gsc-frank](http://askubuntu.com/users/102032/gsc-frank) ... see this article [http://askubuntu.com/questions/235532/how-can-i-install-moonlight-for-chrome-in-12-04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235532/how-can-i-install-moonlight-for-chrome-in-12-04) and try to perform as shown. This help is a contribution provide by mr. [devav2](http://askubuntu.com/users/49542/devav2) I hope to have helped you.

Comment: @RonaldoOliveira After [some problems](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254643/ho-to-install-an-already-downloaded-crx-file-extension-in-chrome) I installed the plugin but [still don't know if it is working well or not](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254666/how-to-know-if-chrome-moonlight-plugin-is-working-fine).

Comment: @Flabricorn I need silverlight to see silverlight made pages ;)

Comment: @gsc-frank Have you tried a wine installation?

Comment: What do you mean? Run Chrome on Wine?

Comment: As indicated in the comments thus far, your best bet is probably an emulator.  But why are you trying to run a Microsoft app on a Google product in linux?  People have reported using Silverlight in IE through WINE.

Moonlight, by all reports, is no longer supported.  What are you trying to do?  Is this a Netflix issue?

Comment: Well, just cos I usually use chrome and hate browser switching while working, and occasionally had the need to access Silverlight app and not have windows installed ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend installing Piperlight. In my ubuntu 13.10  and folowing the steps here
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html
it works smoth

Answer (score 0):

You can't install Silverlight on Linux because that would make Bill cry.

Instead, install Wine, install a browser in Wine, then install Silverlight in the browser.

Comment: I know that path, I just wanted know if were possible without abandon the Chrome that I usually use on my Ubuntu box, in fact, seem to me that for some time was possible, but at least when I try months ago, not work cos Moonlight is kind of unsupported now.