# how can I install moonlight for Chrome in 12.04?

Tags: google-chrome, moonlight

I'd like to install the latest Moonlight version to use it with Google Chrome (not Chromium)

Comment: I just tried that, and it worked. Before it would say "Apps extensions and user scripts cannot be added from this website" but when I went to Chrome://extensions and dragged it in there, it installed perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: Still get the error "Apps extensions and user scripts cannot be added from this website" even when I drag the .crx-file to the "**chrome://chrome/extensions/**"-tab.

Comment: @pinkpony Start Chrome/Chromium with the `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install` flag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at the Moonlight project page *http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx* (this link returns 403. Use [this alternative link](http://mokeke.sytes.net/downloads/linux/Novell_Moonlight/)):

Steps to install Moonlight

1. Download the .crx file from [here](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/downloads/3.99.0.3/novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-i586.crx) (alternative link: [here](http://mokeke.sytes.net/downloads/linux/Novell_Moonlight/novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-i586.crx)).
2. Open **chrome://chrome/extensions/** in a new tab and drag the the .crx file onto the page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Moonlight has a new website at http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page but I couldn't find the Chrome plugin from there, so the plugin may no longer be maintained.

Comment: From one of the suggested links above I found the following google drive page: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0xVGvAbM6Zkb2YzQnhyZXVmYzg&usp=sharing#list

Answer (score 3):

you could have a crack at this:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

good luck!