# Microsoft Media Pack for Moonlight

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, moonlight

I recently reinstalled my computer, a few days ago. Now I have to watch a video lecture. To watch these you need Silverlight. So I installed Moonlight. Now Moonlight needs the Microsoft Media Pack which is provided by Microsoft indeed. Microsoft, on 17 May, decided to take those offline (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2847523/en-us)) since Moonlight is not being developed any more. Now I can't watch my video lectures...

Does someone know how to fix this and how I can install the Microsoft Media Pack?

I need "silverlight-media-pack-linux-x64-21-1.so" file by the way.

Comment: Well now I just installed Wine 1.4.1 with the latest Firefox version for windows and Silverlight.

Comment: Does anyone have this codec pack to download?

Comment: try [Pipelight](http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-08/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html).

Comment: @WG- Please convert your comment to an answer so that others may benefit! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to this link [how can I install moonlight for Chrome in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235532/how-can-i-install-moonlight-for-chrome-in-12-04?rq=1) you may find the answer, or you may have already found an answer as the question is nearly 2 months old!