# How to install an already downloaded .crx file extension in chrome?

Tags: software-installation, chrome-extension

It download the .crx file from [novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-x86_64.crx](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/downloads/3.99.0.3/novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-x86_64.crx) and then went to

> chrome://extensions/

and drag and drop the file on the chrome windows opened in that address and the following message appear

> Apps, extensions, and users scripts cannot be added from this website

with an "OK" button and nothing more.

I read something about "ExtensionInstallSources", but not know how configure it to install extensions from a local directory. Any idea? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Comment: Click on developer mode checkbox

Comment: A more complete answer that tracks recent changes is at [userscripts - How to install a private user script in Chrome 21+? - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/450893/how-to-install-a-private-user-script-in-chrome-21)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a known issue.

Download the .crx file. Drag and drop the downloaded `novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-i586.crx` file into Google chrome browser.

If you get any error mentioning "Apps extensions and user scripts cannot be added from this website", open `chrome://chrome/extensions/` in a new tab and now repeat the step 1

Comment: Thanks, I just restart my PC and works first time, not need to open a new tab for second time. Maybe the issue was related to a recently Chrome update, after witch I not restart Chrome neither my PC.